# Migrate MySql Database To New Server

Tags: mysql, ssh, database-migration, plesk

I have done an export of my database to an .sql file.

When I try and upload this to my new server it comes up as access denied for user 'username' @ '%'

The original database is called 'originalUsername_databaseName' where as it appears that the new server requires the prefix 'admin_'

I am convinced that it is the database name that is causing the error. Is there a way to change this ?

Comment: The error message says that the problem is permissions: you don't have the appropriate GRANTs. Database dump files made by `mysqldump` don't contain the database name, so you can migrate to a different database with no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your sql file does not contain CREATE DATABASE and USE statements.
If it does, remove them.

Create database manually and import tables to it.